# Does gcc have a pragma to define file type/compiler?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, pragma

GCC automatically switches between compilers based on file extension (.c, .cc), by command line parameter (-x) or by calling the appropriate compiler directly (g++ as opposed to gcc, say).

Is there any way to override these using a pragma inside of a file?

Updated, after comment:

I'm converting a code base that is currently 50/50 C & C++ to be entirely compiled with the C++ compiler. This is to allow the current "C" modules to call onto a new C++ base that I cannot change (and don't wish to wrap). I would like to keep the extension as .c for the files that really are C, even though they now have C++ linkage. I think leaving them as ".c" indicates why they are as they are (I'm thinking of future generations here! ;-) ) but it's also a large job to change the build system to accommodate each changed C file name. Even worse, a tiny subset of C files won't convert to C++ sanely, so providing they don't call onto the C++ base I want to leave them as C. Rewriting them isn't an option though, the risks to the stability of the project are too great.

Comment: The obvious solution is to name your C files with a `.c` suffix and your C++ files with a `.cc` or `.cpp` suffix. I can't think of any reason not to use such a convention. Is there something in your environment that prevents you from doing this?

Comment: @KeithThompson I've updated the question, since I had too much to write in a comment! :-)

Comment: A source file compiled by a C++ compiler is a C++ source file, and should have a `.cpp`or `.cc` suffix. I understand it's a large job to change the build system for the changed file names, but I think that's the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned having a build system issue that prompted this question.  I once solved a similar problem by using comments in the source file.  I used a Makefile rule like:

```
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) `if head -1 $< | grep -q 'C++'; then echo '-x c++'; else echo '-x c'; fi` -c -o $@ $<
```

Now if a source file began with a comment line like `/* C++ */` it would be compiled as C++ and otherwise it would be compiled as C (regardless of whether `CC=gcc` or `CC=g++`)

Answer (score 1):

No.

[The documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-x-64) for the `-x none` option states:

> Turn off any specification of a language, so that subsequent files are handled according to their file name suffixes (as they are if -x has not been used at all).

So, there's no mention of further mechanisms, which makes me conclude that they don't exist.

Also note that your idea contains a logic problem: `#pragma` is a feature of some languages, so using it to specify which language is being used is very chicken-and-eggy.

Comment: Yeah, it felt chicken and eggy, but in my case I'm switching only between C & C++. So it's valid (sort of). I'm trying to sidestep a build system issue.